# Обработать wheelEvent в QtGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, события

Хочу реализовать масштабирование в QtGraphicsView через колесико мыши. На данный момент делаю это через фильтр событий следующим способом:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    if (target == ui->graphicsView || event->type() == QEvent::Wheel) {
        QWheelEvent *wheelEvent = static_cast<QWheelEvent *>(event);
        int delta = wheelEvent->delta();
        double scalePlus = 1.2;
        double scaleMinus = 0.8;
        if(delta > 0){
            ui->graphicsView->scale(scalePlus, scalePlus);
            qDebug() << "delta = " << delta;
        } else {
             ui->graphicsView->scale(scaleMinus, scaleMinus);
            qDebug() << "delta = " << delta;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
}
```

Работает это ровно до того, как появляется ScrollBar. После этого колесико мыши просто начинает перехватываться скрулбаром. Как это обойти? Можно и вариант с переопредлелением класса и функции.

Comment: А что если к проверке `target == ui->graphicsView` добавить и тот виджет-скроллбар? Должен быть  доступен `ui->graphicsView->horizontalScrollBar()` и `ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()`. Либо, вообще запретите показываться скролам

Comment: То же самое. Если отключить скролбары, то они просто не будут отображаться, но колесо все равно будет "скролить", а не масштабировать.

Comment: А вы попробуйте у `ui->graphicsView->viewport()` ловить (ну и подписать его на фильтр)

Comment: Вы были правы в предыдущем сообщении. Перехватывание `ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()` сработало после того, как я подписал его на фильтр `ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()->installEventFilter(this)` . А до этого не работало, соответственно, потому что не было   `ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()->installEventFilter(this);` Спасибо.

Comment: Предложу более простой вариант - сделать потомка класса `QGraphicsView`, у которого переопределить `wheelEvent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно было добавить фильтрацию событий вертикального скролла `graphicsView` через:

```
ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()->installEventFilter(this)
```

А после в функции фильтра событий добавить в проверку скролл:

```
if ((target == ui->graphicsView || target == ui->graphicsView->verticalScrollBar()) && event->type() == QEvent::Wheel) {
```